# first-child and nth-child selectors on HTML5 "article" tag not being applied

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm using some CSS2 and CSS3 selectors on a HTML5 `<article>` tag, but it seems a few (but not all) of them aren't working as I'd expect.

Here's a runnable example:

```css
/* Working as expected: */
div.wrapper p:first-child { color: red; }
div.wrapper p:nth-child(even) { color: fuchsia; }

/* NOT working as expected: */
div.wrapper article:nth-child(1) { color: blue; }
div.wrapper article:first-child { color: green; }

/* Working as expected: */
div.wrapper article:last-child { color: gold; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>P1, expected "color: red"</p>
  <p>P2, expected "color: fuchsia"</p>
  <p>P3, expected no css applied</p>
  <p>P4, expected "color: fuchsia"</p>
  <article>Article 1, expected "color: green" and/or "color: blue" &larr; not working as expected...</article>
  <article>Article 2, expected "color: gold"</article>
</div>
```

My problem then is: why won't the `nth-child(n)` and `first-child` selectors on `<article>` tags work? And even weirder: the `last-child` selector does work. I tested in FF4, IE9 and Chrome11, all the same results.

The `<p>` tags function as a a sanity check; to see that the `nth-child(n)` selector does work for some tags.

What am I missing? Is my sample supposed to work at all?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`first-child` only selects the tag if it is the first child tag of its parent tag. In your case, the first `<article>` tag is the fifth tag overall. 
Same goes for `nth-child(n)`. It is not related to sibling tags of the same type, but to all sibling tags. From W3C :

> The :nth-child(an+b) pseudo-class notation represents an element that has an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for any positive integer or zero value of n, and has a parent element.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: And now that you pointed me in the right direction, I also see that there's a `first-of-type` selector which solves my remaining problem. Tx again! If anyone's interested, this is the one I used now: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo

Comment: Cool, I didn't even know the `first-of-type` selector!

Answer (score 6):

The `article` element in your example is a 5th child not a first child. `:first-child` and `nth-child(1)` select the first child of the *parent*.

The `:first-of-type` (or `:nth-of-type(1)`) selector however will select the first element of type `article`.